# How to use JSP as a template without serving it as a webpage

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets, jinja2

Per my understanding JSP is something to serve to the client. But is it possible to use JSP simply as a template to dynamically assemble an html page, which I then serve to the client? What I mean is this

1. A servlet receives the call from the user
2. After some computation, my servlet calls the JSP to assemble the html page dynamically
3. The servlet gets or converts the JSP "result" (the resulting html page) to a String
4. The servlet can now do whatever it wants with that String. It can return it as an html webpage or it can store it in a database, or whatever. After all, the string here is a proper html page/text.

For comparison, Python has Jinja2, which does exactly what I just explained. The closest thing to Jinja2 in Java seems to be JSP.

I need a template to assemble html pages dynamically. If I can use the JSP as above then that will solve my problem in Java. Notice that I don't care for JSP per se. I just need a template similar to Jinja2 (if I could use Jinja2 in Java on App-Engine that would be ideal). Also I am very new to JSP. So if you have an answer, please format it as an example; that would be truly helpful.

I am migrating from Python App-Engine to Java App-Engine for business reasons.

Comment: As a side note. I have been looking at JinJava https://github.com/HubSpot/jinjava, but for whatever reason I cannot get it to work in app-engine. So alternatively, an example of Jinja2 inside an App-Engine servlet would do.

Comment: JSP is used for server-side programming not client-side. JSP is converted to a servlet and works as a servlet once deployed.

Comment: you can let the server render your html in a freemarker template. think its better suited for this than a jsp..freemarker is just a templating engine

Comment: wow, FreeMarker sounds like what I need. Do you know if it is supported by App-Engine and how I might incorporate it into my App-Engine project?

Comment: JSP and Servlets can definitely do what you want them to do. For assembly there is the <jsp:include> action. To convert a response to a String, there is the JSTL action <c:import>. For your requirement, you would use something like  <c:import var="result" url="your.jsp" />. If you need help, then we could post demonstration code here.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you'll need to jump through quite a few hoops, the details of which are dependent on the specific container - in this case appengine.

A quick summary:

- create a fake httpservletresponse, wrapping an output stream you access after rendering. You cannot use a httpservletresponsewrapper, even though the spec permits it this environment won't
- store all request attributes in a map, you'll restore these afterwards in case they've been mutated
- use requestdispatcher.include, passing in the real request and your synthetic response
- restore request attributes
- read string from the outputstream

Be particularly careful of side effects to your request/response, for example the constraints around only calling one of getwriter or getoutputstream, as well as finalizing the request (setting status or content length)

Or just use one of velocity, handlebars, freemarker or the various other Java templating languages. They'll all be much more straightforward.